# Order By DateTime With 00:00:00 Last

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, order-by

`order by datetimecolumn` orders a `datetime` column like this:

```
datetimecolumn   
2014-09-04 00:00:00
2014-09-04 00:00:00
2014-09-04 01:00:00
2014-09-05 00:00:00
2014-09-05 01:00:00
2014-09-05 02:00:00
```

How can I order the data so the the values with 00:00:00 are last, but still order the values ascending by time like so:

```
datetimecolumn    
2014-09-04 01:00:00
2014-09-04 00:00:00
2014-09-04 00:00:00
2014-09-05 01:00:00
2014-09-05 02:00:00
2014-09-05 00:00:00
```

Dumb business rule, I know I know... basically if "user" does not spec a time, the time does not matter (so it goes to the bottom of the list).

Comment: How do you differentiate between them "not specifying a time" and them specifying a time of midnight?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First order by just the date, then prioritize the values where the timestamp is not midnight over those where it is.

```
ORDER BY CONVERT(DATE, col),
  CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE,col) = col     
  THEN 2 ELSE 1 END,
  CONVERT(TIME, col);
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way:

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, col) = col
        THEN DATEADD(day, 1, col) 
        ELSE col
    END ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Give them a weight to differentiate between rows with time 00:00:00 and the rest

```
ORDER BY datetimecolumn,
CASE WHEN cast(datetimecolumn as time)='00:00:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
       cast(datetimecolumn as time)
```

Comment: I apologize but my data was not clear before, I have updated the question. 
Your answer works if all the `date`s are the same, if possible I would like it to honor date part also. Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: @mxmissile Just invert the ORDER first the date col then the CASE.

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding the conditional statement:

```
order by Cast(<DateTimeColumn> as date) asc
       , DateAdd(Second, -1, Cast(<DateTimeColumn> as time)) asc
```

First we simply order by the date segment and then we shift the time segment backwards by 1 unit (I chose a precision of seconds for this example but you can make it as precise as you want) and order on the result. This works because the time will simply wrap around.

Answer (score 0):

Don't sort by the values that you have, rather have a function that coerces the date strings and then sort by the results of that function. Your result will be one column that contains the data you want, and a second column that contains the sort information:

```
datecolumn             datesort
2014-09-04 00:00:00    2014-09-04 B 00:00:00
2014-09-04 00:00:00    2014-09-04 B 00:00:00
2014-09-04 01:00:00    2014-09-04 A 01:00:00
2014-09-05 02:00:00    2014-09-05 A 02:00:00
2014-09-05 00:00:00    2014-09-05 B 00:00:00
2014-09-05 01:00:00    2014-09-05 A 01:00:00
```

gets sorted as:

```
datecolumn             datesort
2014-09-04 01:00:00    2014-09-04 A 01:00:00
2014-09-04 00:00:00    2014-09-04 B 00:00:00
2014-09-04 00:00:00    2014-09-04 B 00:00:00
2014-09-05 01:00:00    2014-09-05 A 01:00:00
2014-09-05 02:00:00    2014-09-05 A 02:00:00
2014-09-05 00:00:00    2014-09-05 B 00:00:00
```

As a best practice (and to ensure that the sort order is consistent regardless of any other variables) I add the PK as the last sort expression. This way any additional data for 09-04 00:00 will always appear in the same order.